# Insert into table with while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good day. I want to insert value into my tblEvaluation.

**This is my code**
**HTML**

```
<form  method="POST" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
            <?php

        $query = "select * from tblEvaluation";
        $request = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());?>
        <h3>Evaluation</h3>
        <table class="table table-hover" style="width:auto;">
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($request)) {

            ?>
        <tr>
        <td style="width:20px;"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control" name="question[]" readonly style="width:250px;"><?php echo $row['Question']; ?></textarea></td>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="id[]">
        <td><select class="form-control" name="answer[]">
        <option>Excellent</option>
        <option>Very Good</option>
        <option>Good</option>
        <option>Need Improvement</option>
        <option>Poor</option>
        </select></td></tr>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
        </table>
        <div style="float:right;"> 
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="evaluate" value="Evaluate">
        <input type="button" value="Back" class="btn btn-danger" name="Back" onclick="window.location.href='client-home.php'">
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['evaluate'])) {
$count = count($_POST['answer']); //get total number of array element
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { // loop through array and assign values in variable and insert itin database
    $answer = $_POST['answer'][$i];
    $id   = $_POST["id"][$i];
        $sql = "Insert into tblEvaluation (Answer) VALUES ('$answer') Where id = '$id'";
        $success = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        if ($success == TRUE) {
            ?>
            <script>
                alert('You have successfully update account.');
            window.location.href='client-home.php';
            </script>

        <?php
        }
         else {
            ?>
            <script>
                alert('Error.');
            </script>

        <?php
        }

}
```

}
This is the error that im getting
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Where id = '17'' at line 1**

I guess it's on the loop but i don't know what to do.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Quick fix: `$answer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['answer'][$i]);`

Comment: I use input type="hidden"

Comment: and also print your query and try to run it in phpmyadmin, you will get a clear picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no where clause in Insert Query.
You can use Update query instead (is data already exixts);
e.g

```
Update table set column='value' where id='yourid';
```

Comment: This is my query (  $sql = "Insert into tblEvaluation (Answer) VALUES ('$answer') Where id = '$id'";)

Comment: use $sql = update tblEvaluation set Answer='$answer' where id='$id'